# ALSA won't detect card when it exists

Tags: linux, audio, kubuntu, alsa

I am a bit stuck with fixing my audio in Kubuntu 18 (same was with Kubuntu 16).   The only sound device I have in tray is "Dummy output"

```
kosyakov@kosyakov-XPS13:~$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A 10 -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 134
        Memory at dc428000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at dc400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

However,

```
kosyakov@kosyakov-XPS13:~$ aplay -l 
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

So far what I tried is reloading alsa service, reloading pulseaudio and all other popular advices and tutorials.

```
kosyakov@kosyakov-XPS13:~$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_intel8x0           40960  0
snd_ac97_codec        131072  1 snd_intel8x0
snd_soc_skl            90112  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi           16384  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          241664  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  2 snd_ac97_codec,snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          40960  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  9 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_core,snd_ac97_codec,snd_soc_skl,snd_intel8x0,snd_soc_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  12 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_ac97_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_intel8x0,snd_seq_device,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

And devices I have:

```
kosyakov@kosyakov-XPS13:~$ sudo find /dev/ | grep snd
/dev/snd
/dev/snd/seq
/dev/snd/timer
```

So far I am stuck with how to make ALSA detect my card.  I would appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Are more devices listed in `/proc/asound/devices`?

Comment: Also look in `dmesg` directly after boot for sound-related messages and error messages (e.g. "missing codec"). Were those modules loaded automatically, or is this list the result of "popular advices and tutorials"? If yes, please edit question and add the module list how it is after boot. (BTW, blindly following some tutorials without understanding the problem usually doesn't help). From the module list, it looks like the card is detected just fine, and there's even a codec for it.